# Twilio: How can the SHAKEN/STIR status of an incoming call be accessed by the Webhook?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Programmable Voice [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/trusted-calling-using-shakenstir#stirverstat-interpretation) indicate that the SHAKEN/STIR status is passed to the webhook for incoming calls, but I don't see it in the POST data. I wouldn't expect it in Lookups since that's not real-time, and I don't see it there either.

My set up is: a Twilio phone number, configured for Voice & Fax to accept incoming voice calls and POST them to a Webhook on my own server.

*Added Information:*

I think the issue may be threefold:

1. incoming calls without SHAKEN/STIR data won't have the parameter;
2. very few calls have SHAKEN/STIR data (based on my call logs)
   (not sure why... even legitimate calls from major U.S. carrier numbers don't have it)
3. SHAKEN/STIR support in forwarded calls is "coming later"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog covers the topic.

Building SHAKEN/STIR verification Into Your Voice CAPTCHA IVR

https://www.twilio.com/blog/shaken-stir-verification-voice-captcha-ivr

Comment: Thanks, looks like Studio has it handled, but I'm not using Studio. I'm using custom code on my own server as the incoming call webhook. I only have access to the POSTed data from Twilio, or what I can lookup.I clicked through to all of the linked articles too, and didn't find anything there.

Comment: StirVerstat Is the key in the webhook, https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/trusted-calling-using-shakenstir

Comment: Thanks, yes, I amended my question above... still a little mysterious why so many seemingly legitimate calls don't have any Shaken/Stir status (and therefore no StirVerstat key).

Comment: Early days. SHAKEN/STIR is mandatory for many telcos by June 30, 2021 and the signature is sent over the SIP signaling, for calls over IP infrastructure.

Comment: Tough to test given how rare it is, but I'll consider this solved.